# What if I keep holding a household battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

I have a question in my mind. What if I keep holding a Duracell(1.5V Battery) touching both the terminals with my fingertips? Will the circuit be completed and the battery drain? Or will it have no effect? Why?

Comment: The battery will drain anyway. They don't last forever, even in the package.  I suppose you want to know if it will drain faster than that?

Comment: Yes, Brick. But why doesn't the cell get hot. Like, if we connect a wire directly across the terminals, the cell gets hot. Why doesn't it happen so in this case?

Comment: FYI: Long-term exposure to small D.C. currents can be harmful to your body tissues. Do not go to sleep with that battery taped to your hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the electrical resistance of your fingers.  [This Aricle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury) shows that the human body has a resistance of up to 100,000 ohms.  Air has a resistance of about 2 x 10^16 ohms.  While a very long thick wire has a resistance of 4 ohms.  So, it looks like your fingers would indeed conduct electricity faster than air, but you'd have to hold the battery for a REALLY long time before you drain it.

Comment: Re, "the human body has a resistance of 100,000 ohms." That is not what the article says at all. It says that if you attempt to measure the electrical resistance of a live human, you can get readings _as high as_ 100,000 Ohms, and as low as 500 Ohms depending on where and how the electrodes are attached to the body.

Comment: Re, "A long thick wire has a resistance of 4 Ohms." How long is "long?" How thick is "thick?" The DC resistance of a segment of metal wire will be proportional to the length, and inversely proportional to the cross section. For a thousand feet of #12 copper wire (long enough for you?) it's less than 1.6 Ohms.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/wirega.html

Comment: @SolomonSlow  yes, you are correct.  Also that the resistance figure for a wire is for a 1000 meter long wire.  It would be much less than for a 4cm wire. And the resistance of air depends on the humidity of the air.  But I was trying to get across in a very simple manner, that a human body is FAR more resistant than a wire, so it would take a long time, but not forever, to drain the battery.

Comment: To expand on @SolomonSlow 's comment, resistance is an extensive property, not intensive (i.e. a property on an object, not a substance). The unit here should be Ohm-meters, not Ohms (a substance having 1 Ohm-meter means that resistance in Ohm equals length in m divided by cross-sectional area in m^2).